# In Spring Data Redis, how to pass multiple keys into leftpop() (rightpop()) method with timeout?

Tags: java, spring, redis, redis-cli

As far as I'm concerned, [this method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ListOperations.html#leftPop-K-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) is similar to [BLPOP](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) command in redis-cli. The latter, however, is able to get multiple lists in its signature.

Is it possible with leftPop() method too? From docs:

> Removes and returns first element from lists stored at key .

It seems that it is possible, but I can't realize how to do it properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `ListOperations` does not support any operation with multiple keys